Json object within the BodyToMono method in WebClient
We are using the Spring Reactive Web Client and I am trying to find the actual Json within the response object. Within the following code when I have a breakpoint set. The Json that we know is being returned, is not in the body object that I would expect. Or I cant find it...
private <T> Publisher<T> handleBodyFlux(ClientResponse response, Flux<T> body) {
            body = body.onErrorResume(WebClientUtils.WRAP_EXCEPTION_PREDICATE, exceptionWrappingFunction(response));
            Mono<T> result = applyStatusHandlers(response);
            return (result != null ? result.flux().switchIfEmpty(body) : body);


So, what I understood is, you are trying to debug the code. You setup a debug point and try to see the body here. But it didn't work.
It won't because its not fetched at that time.
Use .log() on your publisher to see the values when subscription happens. You will anyway not be able to use any blocking mechanism in this code.
